# My last code output become in the center not from left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, code

This is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
take an example of $$3\sqrt{5}.$$

$$3\sqrt{5}$$ $$means$$ $$3\cdot {\sqrt{5}}$$

\centering To express that in the form of surds, I'm going to square the expressions.

$$(3\cdot\sqrt{5})^2$$

$$= 9\cdot5$$

\centering Take square root of both expression
$$\sqrt{9}\cdot\sqrt{5}$$

Simplify that to

$$\sqrt{45}$$ 

Which is surds.\\

Back to the questions, What is larger, $2\sqrt{2}$, or $1 + \sqrt{3}$?
\end{document}
```

The `Back to the questions` line get in the center. Help :"

**Screenshot**:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of code snippets.

Comment: To center just a part of the document, use `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` rather than `\centering` which centers the full remaining document.

Comment: Maybe in this particular case you could use `\begin{gather*}...\end{gather*}` with `\intertext{}` for many of the short lines of text between the equations. By the way you should not use `$$...$$`, is better to use `\[...\]` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854/140456

Answer (score 1):

There is an awful lot you're doing wrong here.

First up: `$$`…`$$` is not correct LaTeX markup. You should use `\[`…`\]` if you want display math and `$`…`$` or `\(`…`\)` if you want inline math. I'm guessing that you really wanted in-line math for a lot of what you wrote. Not to mention that

```
$$3\sqrt{5}$$ $$means$$ $$3\cdot {\sqrt{5}}$$
```

will set three displayed equations with the middle one being

> *m e a n s*

I'm guessing you really meant to write

```
$3\sqrt{5}$  $3\cdot {\sqrt{5}}$
```

Also, don't put blank lines before displayed math. Write:

```
Simplify that to
\[
  \sqrt{45}
\]
```

instead of

```
Simplify that to

$$\sqrt{45}$$
```

(The line breaks in my version aren't essential, but it helps offset the displayed math in your `.tex` file for easier source readability.)

The `\\` is going to put a blank line there. I'm not sure you wanted that.

**And for the main question of the post**, to get a centered block of text,¹ rather than use `\centering` you should use a `center` environment` instead which will indicate where the centered text should appear.²

```
\begin{center}
Take square root fo both expressions
\[
  \sqrt{9}\cdot\sqrt{5}
\]
Simplify that to
\[
  \sqrt{45}
\]
which is surds.
\end{center}
```

---

1. Although this should really be wrapped up in a new environment with some semantic meaning, but I'll let that slide for now.
2. It also adds some vertical space before and after which is probably appropriate for this case.

Comment: Please be kind to a novice ;-)

Comment: I see, Thanks! I'm just starting learning LaTeX :"